# SAX Parser Exception

Tags: java, xml, xsd

getting this error:

SAX Parser Exception.

cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'xs:schema'.

with this xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"targetNamespace="http://nrg.wustl.edu/tx"  xmlns:tx="http://nrg.wustl.edu/tx" xmlns:xnat="http://nrg.wustl.edu/xnat" xmlns:xdat="http://cnl.wustl.edu/xdat" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://nrg.wustl.edu/xnat" schemaLocation="../xnat/xnat.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://cnl.wustl.edu/xdat" schemaLocation="../xdat/xdat.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="MedicationTreatmentList" type="tx:medTreatmentList" />
    <xs:element name="TreatmentList" type="tx:treatmentList" />
    <xs:element name="ChemotherapyTreatment" type="tx:chemotherapyTreatment" />
    <xs:element name="RadiationTreatment" type="tx:radiationTreatment" />
    <xs:complexType name="medTreatment">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="codeType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <xdat:field uniqueComposite="NAME_DATE_FK"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="doseAmount" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="doseUnit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="doseSchedule" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="route" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="indication" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="startDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <xdat:field uniqueComposite="NAME_DATE_FK"/>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="startDateDayNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="startDateMonthNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="startDateYearNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="endDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="endDateDayNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="endDateMonthNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="endDateYearNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="clinicalTrialName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="clinicalTrialArm" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="treatmentNotes" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="1000" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="medTreatmentList">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="xnat:subjectAssessorData">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="medTreatments" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="medTreatment" type="medTreatment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:appinfo>
                                            <xdat:field>
                                                <xdat:relation uniqueComposite="NAME_DATE_FK" relationType="single"/>
                                            </xdat:field>
                                        </xs:appinfo>
                                    </xs:annotation>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="treatment">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="code" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="codeType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="doseAmount" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="doseUnit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="doseSchedule" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="route" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="indication" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="startDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="startDateDayNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="startDateMonthNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="startDateYearNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="endDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="endDateDayNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="endDateMonthNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="endDateYearNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="clinicalTrialName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="clinicalTrialArm" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
            <xs:element name="treatmentNotes" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="1000" />
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="treatmentList">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="xnat:subjectAssessorData">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="treatments" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="treatment" type="tx:treatment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:annotation>
                                        <xs:appinfo>
                                            <xdat:field>
                                                <xdat:relation relationType="multi" relationName="tx_treatmentList_treatment"/>
                                            </xdat:field>
                                        </xs:appinfo>
                                    </xs:annotation>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="baseTreatment">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="xnat:subjectAssessorData">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="unit" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="dose" type="xs:float" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="timing" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="startDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="startDateDayNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="startDateMonthNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="startDateYearNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="endDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="endDateDayNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="endDateMonthNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="endDateYearNotReported" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="completed" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="incompleteReason" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="incompleteExtent" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="clinicalTrialName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="clinicalTrialArm" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                    <xs:element name="completedNotes" minOccurs="0">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                <xs:maxLength value="1000" />
                            </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="chemotherapyTreatment">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tx:baseTreatment" />
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="radiationTreatment">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="tx:baseTreatment" />
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The declaration looks to be correct from what I can see. I have gone over this several times and can't come up with anything. Any thoughts?

Comment: you haven't provided many details as to what you are actually _doing_, but is it possible you are parsing using a parser which is not namespace aware?

Comment: SAX Parser is namespace aware

Comment: The schema looks fine. Can you please post/check the relevant parts of `xnat.xsd` and `xdat.xsd` ?

Comment: @user1332868 - are you saying that you configured your SAXParser to be namespace aware (it's not configured that way by default)?

Comment: it would be helpful if you showed some example code and maybe what you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your declaration is invalid. You are missing a space before targetNameSpace.

Answer (score 0):

problem in spacing it should be

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://nrg.wustl.edu/tx"  xmlns:tx="http://nrg.wustl.edu/tx" xmlns:xnat="http://nrg.wustl.edu/xnat" xmlns:xdat="http://cnl.wustl.edu/xdat" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">`